# create a variable and add to a data frame within a loop in R using existing variable

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to add a variable to a data frame using a for loop in r. The for loop is supposed to run through an existing variable (NetMig) in the data frame (cs) and output a new variable (PNM). PNM is supposed to take a value of 1 if NetMig is greater than 0 and takes a value of 0 otherwise. Here is my code so far.

```
    for(i in 1:227) {
     if(cs$NetMig[i] > 0) {
        cs$PNM[i] <- 1
        else {
          cs$PNM[i] <- 0
        }
      }
    }
```

An error keeps popping up

Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `PNM`.
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `PNM`.

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: R is vectorised, so you don't need to iterate through all the elements in each column vector. Try `cs$PNM <- as.numeric(cs$NetMig > 0)` rather than a loop with conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the column before you run the `for` loop:

```
cs$PNM <- c()
for(i in 1:227) {
 if(cs$NetMig[i] > 0) {
    cs$PNM[i] <- 1
    else {
      cs$PNM[i] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

As noted by others, there's no need for the loop. This would do the same trick:

```
cs$PNM <- ifelse(cs$NetMig > 0, 1, 0)
```